# How to pass hidden ID value to another page using onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how do I pass the hidden value to another page using onclick
here is my code:

```
<button type="button" id="requestthis" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="pass()"><a href="submitrequest.php">Request</a></button>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_user_id">
```

I used this function but it didn't seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pass(id)
    {
        url: 'submitrequest.php'+id;
    }
</script>
```

Other sites I visited didn't do any help.

Anyone who could point out where did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are tons of issues here. **1:** You're not passing anything with your `onclick="pass()"`. **2:** You seem to be attempting to make a `url` variable, but using `:`, which is syntactically incorrect. **3:** This won't do anything because it's not a function - you need `window.location` or something along those lines. **4:** Even if you were properly redirecting to that link, it would look like `submitrequest.php5` which is not what you want. You need a querystring, like `submitrequest.php?id=5`.

Comment: There is a actually a hidden value there when I checked the browser console the `<button type="button" id="requestthis" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="pass()"><a href="submitrequest.php">Request</a></button>` becomes `<button type="button" id="requestthis" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="pass()" value="6"><a href="submitrequest.php">Request</a></button>` it shows a value of 6 as shown.

Comment: It doesn't matter what `value` is in this case because you aren't passing it. You pass something to the function by including it in the parentheses, which as you can see in your `onclick="pass()"`, are empty.

Comment: Thanks +1 to all who helped . Thank you too @Santi I'm glad to know those and I'm glad I learned from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to avoid inline-event `onClick()` and attach event in the JS code, check example bellow.

**HTML :**

```
<button type="button" id="requestthis" class="btn btn-primary">
    <a href="submitrequest.php">Request</a>
</button>

<input type="hidden" id="hidden_user_id">
```

**JS :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { //ready function
        $('#requestthis').on('click', function(e){ //click event
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent the click from redirecting you to "submitrequest.php"

            var hidden_id = $('#hidden_user_id').val();
            var url = "submitrequest.php?hidden_id="+hidden_id;

            window.location.replace(url);
            //OR 
            //window.location.href = url;
        })
    })
</script>
```

To get the parameter `id` in the other page you have to use `$_GET[]`, example :

```
echo $_GET['hidden_id'];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ZA I modified the code a little into `var hidden_id =` `$('input[type="hidden"]').attr('value');` and `var url =` `"submitrequest.php?id="+hidden_id;'  because with your code it actually reads the attribute `value`  of the hidden input which is `#hidden_user_id` so I used `'value'` in order to pass the actual `id` into the other page. BTW it really helped me a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, glad i could helps.... I've updated the code to get the value of hidden field `var hidden_id = $('#hidden_user_id').val();`, and also added how to get the passed parameter in the new page.

Comment: Wow it worked too. I also tried `$_REQUEST['id']` so how are they different anyway?

Comment: We're passing the variable in the url so it will be concedered as get request and we could find this param in `$_GET[]`, the difference is that `$_REQUEST[]` could get also the parameters passed by post requests as get requests.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass anything to `pass`

```
function pass()
    {
        var hiddenVal = $("#hidden_user_id").val();
        url= 'submitrequest.php?hidden_vale='+hiddenVal;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @RK worked fine I'll just do a little tweaking and play with these, I just wanna ask how do I display the hidden id in the newpage?